# Serialization of detached JDO's in gwt's RemoteService Implementation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jdo, datanucleus

In my RemoteServiceImpl (gwt) i would return an ArrayList. The model has a few members referencing to other objects which are also persistable. The whole object tree comes from gae datastore. I have to detach the objects before returning them in RemoteServiceImpl. Unfortunately after invoking pm.detachCopy() the nested information is lost which was previously present.

```java
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
@FetchGroup(name = "wc", members = {@Persistent(name = "waterConditions",
    recursionDepth =  -1)})
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class InventoryInhabitant implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    private InventoryWaterConditions waterConditions;
    ....
}

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class InventoryWaterConditions implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    private InventoryPh ph;
    ...
}
```

Getter and Setter present just omitted for brevity. After detaching the field waterConditions is not null but it contains nothing all members for example "ph" are null.

What i am do wrong in my case?

Comment: have you set max fetch depth on the FetchPlan?

Comment: I tried @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", recursionDepth = -1) but that didn't work. But please clue me, detachCopy is affected from FetchPlan configuration?

Comment: PM has a FetchPlan, and you can set the max FetchDepth as per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jdo/fetchgroup.html

Comment: Neil, thank you very much, it's working by setting pm.setMaxFetchDepth(-1).

Comment: great, added as an answer so you can accept

Comment: It seems, that i haven't understand this concept in full. detachCopyAll() also cuts of elements in the ArrayList.

Comment: No idea what "cuts of elements in the ArrayList" means ... I see no ArrayList. I also see use of Element on a 1-1/N-1 field (which is wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PersistenceManager has a FetchPlan. A FetchPlan has a maximum "fetch depth" which you can set following this link http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jdo/fetchgroup.html